# flexslider content change on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, flexslider

I am trying to create a flex slider. Where we have button at the top, when the user selects any button the content below it changes using the flex slider, my flexslider is working but I am not able to pass parameter into the jquery to change content.

currently my flexslider js is :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $(window).load(function(){
      $('.cmsslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        selector:'.slidercontent .row',
        animationLoop:true,
        slideshow:false,
        controlsContainer: ".container",
        controlNav: true,
        manualControls: "#thumbnail img",
        slideshowSpeed: 700
      });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like:

```
$("#someBtn").click(function(){
    $(".cmsslider").html("//new content here");
});
```

Comment: content is dynamic coming from drupal,not static content suppose you have A,B,C and content for each is coming from Drupal so that //new content here will vary

Comment: Is it already generated and invisible or has to be retrieved from drupal?

Comment: already generated from drupal now its coming in a structure of rows

Comment: Would you share an example of it in question?